# How do I save the contents of this 2d array to a file

Tags: delphi

I Need some help trying to save the contents of the 2d array into a file.
First of all im not sure what type the file should be etc .txt or dat.

I have edited the post so that the code is in text format not an image.

This is what ive got so far.

```
program CaptureTheSarum;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

Const BoardDimension = 8;

Type
  TBoard = Array[1..BoardDimension, 1..BoardDimension] Of String;

Var
  Board : TBoard;
  GameOver : Boolean;
  StartSquare : Integer;
  FinishSquare : Integer;
  StartRank : Integer;
  StartFile : Integer;
  FinishRank : Integer;
  FinishFile : Integer;
  MoveIsLegal : Boolean;
  PlayAgain : Char;
  SampleGame : Char;
  WhoseTurn : Char;
  savedFile : text;

procedure InitialiseSave;
var
  fileName : string;
begin
  fileName := 'SavedGame.dat';

  assignfile(savedfile,fileName);
  if not fileexists(fileName)
  then
    begin
      rewrite(savedfile);
      closefile(savedfile)
    end
  {endif};
end;

procedure saveGame;
var
 save : string;
 RankNo,FileNo : integer;
begin
  writeln('Would you like to save the Game?');
  readln(save);

  if (save = 'y') or (save = 'Y')
  then
    begin
      reset(SavedFile);
      write(SavedFile,board[fileno,Rankno]);
      closeFile(SavedFile);
    end
  {endif};
```

Comment: Please do *not* put any of your code in an image. First, it's not necessary - code is text. It's much faster to just select it in the code editor, copy it, and paste it into your question here. Second, it prevents copy/paste into an editor to use for developing an answer. Images should be used *only* when needed to demonstrate a problem that can't be described in words. Please [edit] your post to remove the image and replace it with your actual code as text. Thanks.

Comment: You need to decide on the file format. How can we do that for you? How can we give you advice if we don't know your usage, goals, requirements?

Comment: For instance, this looks like chess. There are established chess board file formats. Use one of those and you'll be able to load boards saved with another program. And vice versa. Perhaps this matters. Perhaps not.

Comment: I agree with David Heffernan. If this is a chess board you should follow the established standards where each figure is actually represented by a single character and not the whole string. So in the end the whole board is stored in a single ansi string with the length of 64 characters. First 8 characters represent first line, second 8 characters represent second line etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to make some sort of board game (probably chess).

The main problem you are facing is that you haven't defined your board type as fixed size. You see in Delphi strings are of dynamic size. And while in older versions of Delphi they were limited to 255 characters in newer versions their size is only limited by available memory.

So you should change your board definition (array) to be of fixed type. For most board games you could use 2D array of Char.

```
TBoard = Array [0..7, 0..7] of Char;
```

On older non-Unicode versions of Delphi Char will be an AnsiChar which allows you to store 256 different characters or 256 different figures.

On newer Delphi versions that support Unicode you have even more possibilities.

Anyway the best thing about using static array of fixed type is that you can save the whole static array into a file with a single command

```
procedure SaveGame;
//When having fixed size types you can use File of Type to quickly get
//ability to store whole type at once. 
//Note this only works for fixed sized records who don't contain any 
//dynamic sized members (strings, dynamic arrays) and static arrays of
//fixed sized type (no strings or other dynamic sized arrays)
//
//With arrays it doesn't even matter whether they are one dimensional 
//or multidimensional. but they need to be static
var Savefile: File of TBoard;
    FileName: String;
begin
  Filename := 'D:\Proba.txt';
  //Assign file
  Assignfile(Savefile,FileName);
  //Check if the file exists if it does open it for editing (reser)
  //else open it in rewrite mode which also automatically creates new 
  //file if the file doesn't exists
  if not Fileexists(Filename) then
    Rewrite(Savefile)
  else
    Reset(SaveFile);

  //Becouse we have a file of fixed sized type we can write the whole 
  //type with just one Write command 
  //your program already know how many bytes it has to write
  //
  //Note if you want to store multiple savegames in a single file you
  //need to use seek to move your current position
  //And because we have file of type the seek moves the current position
  //by N times of the type size
  //So if the size of your type is 64 bytes calling Seek(YourFile,2) 
  //will move current position to the 128th byte
  Write(SaveFile, Board);
  //Close file
  CloseFile(SaveFile);
end;
```

Reading the data from your file is done in similar way.

```
Read(Savefile, Board);
```

EDIT: If you are on older version of Delphi and the char does not allow you enough possibilities to store the state of your board cell you can always use array of integers like most other grid based games do.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your main question, you can save a two-dimensional string array as follows:

```
procedure TForm9.FileSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i, j: integer;
  fn: string;
  fs: TFileStream;
  fw: TWriter;
begin
  fn := 'c:\tmp\mychessfile.dat';
  fs := nil;
  fw := nil;
  try
    fs := TFileStream.Create(fn, fmCreate or fmShareDenyWrite);
    fw := TWriter.Create(fs, 1024);
    for i := 1 to BoardDimension do
      for j := 1 to BoardDimension do
        fw.WriteString(Board[i, j]);
  finally
    fw.Free;
    fs.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Subsequently you can read the file back to the array with:

```
procedure TForm9.FileReadClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i, j: integer;
  fn: string;
  fs: TFileStream;
  fr: TReader;
begin
  fn := 'c:\tmp\mychessfile.dat';
  fs := nil;
  fr := nil;
  try
    fs := TFileStream.Create(fn, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
    fr := TReader.Create(fs, 1024);
    for i := 1 to BoardDimension do
      for j := 1 to BoardDimension do
          Board[i, j] := fr.ReadString;
  finally
    fr.Free;
    fs.Free;
  end;
end;
```

As you see I chose the general purpose `.dat` extension, because the file will contain also binary data, like length of each text, data type etc. Those details are dealt with by the `TWriter`/`TReader` classes.

You should also consider the comments you received regarding choise of file structure.
For example, Googling for 'chess file format' (assuming you are working on a chess game), brings up [Portable_Game_Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Game_Notation) and another reference from that page: [Forsyth-Edwards Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation).

Answer (score 0):

INI file like this:

```
[d1]
1=element1
2=element2
...
[d2]
1=element1
...
```

But,recommend XML, like this:

```
<array>
  <d1>
    <element1>value1</element1>
    <element2>value1</element2>
    ...
  </d1>
  <d2>
    <element1>value1</element1>
    ...
  </d2>
</array>
```

Comment: This does not answer the question being asked. This answer has nothing to do with Delphi or the method in which OP is using.

Comment: Both options will be shockingly profligate of space and readability

Comment: @Jerry Not sure I agree. What exactly is the question asking? It's easy to read it that it asks for how to format the file.