# Delphi - Store and read 2d array from text file

Tags: arrays, delphi, multidimensional-array

I am trying to store a 2d array which holds characters, into a text file which is in the comma separated values (CSV) format. I have been semi able to store the array into the text file but i dont think it will allow for it to be read back as there is no new line at the end of the end of each line where the end of the array would be (Board[1][8]) for an example. I have been unable to read the informatoin back into the array.

This is my code for storing the array into the text file

```
Const 
  BoardDimension = 8;

 Type
    TBoard = Array[1..BoardDimension, 1..BoardDimension] Of String;

 procedure SaveGame(Board : Tboard);
    var
      FileNm : Textfile;
      RankCount : Integer;
      FileCount : Integer;
    begin
      Assignfile(Filenm, 'SavedGame.txt');
      Rewrite(Filenm);
      for RankCount :=1 to BoardDimension do
      begin
        for FileCount := 1 to BoardDimension-1 do
          begin
            write(Filenm,Board[RankCount,FileCount],',');
          end;
          write(Filenm,Board[RankCount,BoardDimension]);
      end;
      CloseFile(filenm);
      writeln('game saved');
    end;
```

this is my code for reading the text file back, but i am getting an error which states that the function Copy2SymbDel is undeclared but i have included strutils in the using statement

```
procedure LoadGame(Var Board :TBoard);
    var
      Filenm : TextFile;
      RankCount : Integer;
      FileCount : Integer;
      Text : String;
    begin
      AssignFile(Filenm, 'SavedGame.txt');
      reset(Filenm);
      for RankCount := 1 to BoardDimension do
      begin
        readln(Filenm,text);
        for FileCount := 1 to BoardDimension -1 do
        begin
          Board[RankCount,FileCount] := Copy2SymbDel(Text, ',');
        end;
        Board[RankCount,BoardDimension] := Text;
      end;
    end;
```

How can I store and read back a 2d array in delphi/pascal

Thank you

Comment: `Copy2SymbDel` is not a standard function, which is why adding `StrUtils` didn't help. Where did you get the code that uses it?

Comment: It is hardly depends on the data in the cells of your array. If it is simple data type such as Byte or Integer then it is very simple to save and load it. With strings it's a little more complicated. For the start I can recommend to use: 1) simple text file 2) One value - one line (so, use `Writeln/Readln` for each read/write operation). Please make sure that you are need exactly `string` type in the cells instead of more simple type. Have fun.

Comment: I got the code i am using from a booklet that my teacher gave out. and the  information in the array is "BR" or "WM" and others like that. The only thing information that is in the cells of the array is strings. I amended the code the show the array

Comment: It's a real shame that your teacher has you operating on a chess board as an array of string. Strings should be reserved for serialization.

Comment: @David: How is this not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/30495576/62576? It's the same array declaration with the same definition, and also asks about writing the 2d array to a text file.

Comment: @Ken Maybe. This is clearly a class working with the same materials. It would be fine to close it. I picked up on the compiler error which is certainly novel.

Comment: Can someone please get me contact to this teacher? I would like to have a friendly chat with him. I would like to find out whether he is teaching wrong approach about storing game board data or perhaps just chose a poor example for teaching his pupils about using nested loops or how you can treat any 1D array as 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

[`Copy2SymbDel`](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/strutils/copy2symbdel.html) is a FreePascal library function that is not available in Delphi. It is described like this:

> ```
> function Copy2SymbDel(
>   var S: string;
>   Symb: Char
> ):string;
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> Copy2SymbDel determines the position of the first occurrence of Symb
>   in the string S and returns all characters up to this position. The
>   Symb character itself is not included in the result string. All
>   returned characters and the Symb character, are deleted from the
>   string S, after which it is right-trimmed. If Symb does not appear in
>   S, then the whole of S is returned, and S itself is emptied.

In Delphi the function could be implemented like this:

```
function Copy2SymbDel(var S: string; Symb: Char): string;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  I := Pos(Symb, S);
  if I = 0 then
  begin
    Result := S;
    S := '';
  end
  else
  begin
    Result := Copy(S, 1, I-1);
    S := TrimRight(Copy(S, I+1, MaxInt));
  end;
end;
```